# This C program is supposed to accept a file as input and print the first 5 lines

Tags: c

It's also supposed to accept `-n` as an argument and the amount of lines they want the program to print. Currently it only works for the first part but when I try to use the arguments it only works in this order:
`./a.out test.txt -n 5`
when it's supposed to work in this order:
`./a.out -n 5 test.txt`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char buffer[512];
    char* nlines = "-n";
    int chars_read = read(0, buffer, 512);
    int i;
    int outfile1 = open(argv[1], O_CREAT|O_RDONLY|O_APPEND, 0777);
    int count = 0;

if(argc <3) {
    for(i=0; read(outfile1, &buffer[i], 1);i++) {

        if(buffer[i] == '\n') {
            printf("\n");
            count++;
            }else{
                write(1, &buffer[i], chars_read);
                }
                if(count>4)
                {
                    break;
                    }


    }
    printf("\n");

}else if (strcmp(nlines, argv[2]) == 0) {

    int input = atoi(argv[3]);
    for(i=0; read(outfile1, &buffer[i], 1);i++) {

        if(buffer[i] == '\n') {
            printf("\n");
            count++;
            }else{
                write(1, &buffer[i], chars_read);
                }
                if(count>input-1)
                {
                    break;
                    }
        }

    }else{
        printf("correct format is ./a.out file -n #lines");
        }
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `open(argv[1], O_CREAT|O_RDONLY|O_APPEND, 0777);` uses `argv[1]` as the filename.

Comment: Not related but why do you read stuff from stdin and put it in buffer?  `int chars_read = read(0, buffer, 512);`

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with arguments to a program, the zeroth argument is the executable name. You explicitly use `argv[1]` as the filename, so when you invoke it as "./a.out -n 5 test.txt", that is "-n". A common way to deal with this is to loop over the arguments. Then for each argument check if it's an option, and use the first non-option argument as the filename. Also note that "-n" and "5" will be separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what you're asking it to do: it *always* takes `argv[1]` as the filename; then (if `argc >= 3`), it takes `argv[2]` and `argc[3]` as the "-n 5".

I'll advise you to simplify the code. First of all, parse the input args and store the parameters in variables. Then, do just one main loop. This way, everything will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse and check the parameters.

```
int getlines(char **arg)
{
    int result = -1;
    if(arg[0][0] == '-')
    {
        if(arg[0][1] == 'n')
        {
            if(!arg[1] || sscanf(arg[1], "%d", &result) != 1 || !result) result = -3;
        }
        else
        {
            result = -2;
        }
    } 
    return result;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nlines;
    FILE *fi = NULL;
    if(argc != 4) return -1;

    for(int argn = 1; argn < argc; argn++)
    {
        nlines = getlines(argv + argn);
        switch(nlines)
        {
            case -1:
                if(!fi) 
                {
                    fi = fopen(argv[argn], "r");
                    printf("Error opening file %s\n", argv[argn]);
                    if(!fi) goto cleanup;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Input file already opened. Invalid argument %s\n", argv[argn]);                    
                    goto cleanup;
                }
                break;
            case -2:
                printf("Invalid argument %s\n", argv[argn]);
                goto cleanup;
            case -3:
                printf("Invalid number of lines\n");
                goto cleanup;
            default:
                argn++;

        }
    }

    if(nlines && fi)
    {
        /* print first nlines */
    }
    cleanup:
    if(fi) fclose(fi);
}
```